# Another way to save configurations

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to re-code my existing project (WPF Code-Behind) in MVVM and want to make much better.

In the old project i saved all (including MySQL Connection Info) in App.config.
But I read that this is much unsecure and not recommended. So I want to ask you, whats the best and securest way for MVVM to save and read config.

In the Config I want to store following for example:

bool StayLoggedIn (When Checkbox at login is checked this should be true to stayloggedin, this can be unsecure)
string Mysql_DATABASE (the database)
string Mysql SERVER (the server)
string Mysql User (user)
string Mysql Password (password)

As you can see, people shouldnt see this config file. But the program should be able to read and write this file.

I can't use App.config too because I created 2 Projects in my Solution. 1 for my Views called Ui.Desktop and 1 for my ViewModels called Logic.Ui.
So Logic.Ui doesn't have App.config and I cant get access of the App.Config then. So there have to be another way.

Comment: 3. Common.Stuff library where all config things happening and other projects reference.

Comment: @Reniuz what do you mean with `3. Common.Stuff library` ?

Comment: You can also store ConnectionString with Encryption and whenever you need you should decrypt it.

Comment: Yea but the thing is, i cant access to App.config in Ui.Desktop Project from Logic.Ui Project. So i cant use App.config.

Comment: you have 2 projects. Add new one 3rd. Call it Common or something similar. Add there config and reading/writing methods. Reference this library  in you 2 projects. Boom you have one place for managing config and both project can use it.

Comment: @Reniuz ah okay. Is this safe? I mean. It is possible to decompile C# Applications... And another thing is, this wouldn't work when re-opening the application. Thats why I need something like a file (for example app.config which is not recommended of what i read)

Comment: I don't say to store everything in dll. I am just pointing how you can overcome this problem: `So Logic.Ui doesn't have App.config and I cant get access of the App.Config then`. Second thing, how security is important? How secure is your DB connection? You can encrypt everything in you app.config or other file you store configuration.

Comment: Thats why im asking here :) I dont know how to secure. my db connection for now is simply a string. And im asking how big firms with big application handles this. Im for sure not the first guy who want to have a config file or something else where I can securely save mysql data.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the application configuration file with an encrypted connection string (or whatever other values you need).  If the "Ui.Desktop" project is the solution startup project, that is the one that must have the app.config with the data in it.  That is assuming of course that the "Logic.Ui" project is a reference.
I believe the better question to ask yourself is where are you placing your configuration elements?  If you are building them in your "Logic.Ui" projection that would not be the correct project to do so.  It is called "Separation of Concerns".
A better way of creating this solution might be to create a project that is concerned with starting your application, reading any configuration, and running whatever it is you want to run.  If this is a WPF application place all of your views in a folder called "Views".  If your "Logic.Ui" project has the ViewModel's then you can reference this project and use the classes you build in the "Logic.Ui" project.  Let me know if this is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, im only at stackoverflow if im at my work (actual in education). Yea my Views are in Ui.Desktop and my ViewModels are in Logic.Ui. So what you mean is, I have to add a reference to Dekstop.UI in Logic.UI ? Because I often read that this will "break the mvvm".

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear.  Reference Logic.ui from ui.desktop.  Especially if you make it a project reference, then it will work fine for you. Does that clarify things?